# Onboarding new collator to live network

Tags: parachain-collator, collator

I have set up a PoA parachain network with predefined 2 authorities which are assigned to the two collators joining the network. So far I've figured out how to manually update the chain-spec collatorSelection section to add new collator keys, however, this requires network reset.

I've been trying to use "sudo" from the PolkadotJS app to add new collator keys, but I keep receiving error error: collatorSelection.ValidatorNotRegistered when performing sudo > collatorSelection > setInvulnerables  -- also received the same error when executing registerAsCandidate extrinsic for the target collator account.

So far I didn't find an explicit document that explains the above, any help here would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error because you have not registered your new node as a validator candidate. See this guide with the steps to fix that: [How to add new collators on a running parachain?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/5709/2762)