# How to add new collators on a running parachain?

Tags: parachain, collator

I'm running a Relay Chain with 4 validators. And trying to add a new collator to a running parachain.

Which I've changed the `desiredCandidates` from 0 to 2 in the Chain Specification file. And when I try to add a new collator using the `collatorSelection` pallet I get the error : `collatorSelection.ValidatorNotRegistered` [image: Error]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific error that you are seeing here is because you haven't previously registered the new node as a validator candidate. [Here](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/master/pallets/collator-selection/src/lib.rs#L360) is the source code that generates the error.

The relevant bits are below:

```rust
/// Register this account as a collator candidate. The account must (a) already have
/// registered session keys and (b) be able to reserve the `CandidacyBond`.
///
/// This call is not available to `Invulnerable` collators.
...
pub fn register_as_candidate(origin: OriginFor<T>) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
        let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;

        ...

        let validator_key = T::ValidatorIdOf::convert(who.clone())
            .ok_or(Error::<T>::NoAssociatedValidatorId)?;
        ensure!(
            T::ValidatorRegistration::is_registered(&validator_key),
            Error::<T>::ValidatorNotRegistered
        );
        ...
```

You can see that it asks the config's ValidatorRegistration if the validator key has been registered. Assuming you are using the most common pallets, `pallet-session` is the one that implements the trait, and it has a `set_keys` extrinsic which can be called by the account attempting to become a validator.

You can get session keys from the (usually protected) runtime call `author - rotate_keys`.

So the most likely steps are:

1. Make the runtime call `rotate_keys` in the `author` pallet.
2. Use the keys you get to submit a `set_keys` extrinsic in the `session` pallet. This might require some SCALE-decoding, depending on how you do it.
3. Register as a candidate the way you already do.

However, this might change depending on your chain setup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I`ve done something similar to that. Thanks for the answer !